# Override configurable prices (or load via AJAX)

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-price

So I have an AJAX price loader, which works fine for simple products. However for configurable products and the simple options, I do not get the override working.

I have a javascript that can set the new/correct price in the spConfig after the page is loaded.
Example

```
$('#product_addtocart_form').data('mageConfigurable').options.spConfig.optionPrices[699].basePrice = {amount: 23};
```

The price is correctly show, but the select box is still an incorrect price. How can I re-render the select boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering. Since Magento 2.3 and up changed to ElasticSearch for counting the filters and their values, you would need to alter the way it gets this.